# Updating TimeZone from an application on windows mobile 6.1

Tags: timezone, windows-mobile-6.1

I am trying to update the TimeZone of the windows mobile device from my application using the 
OPenNetCF.WindowsCE.SetTimeZoneInformation call. It always sets the timezone to the standard timezone(ignores the day light timezone) when there are timezones with the same offset. To be clear, say I am trying to set the TimeZone to GMT-5 Eastern (new-york zone, which observes day light) from GMT-7 Arizona (mountain standard) and for some reason, it always sets the new time zone to GMT-5 Indiana (which doesn't observe day light settings).

To confirm if I am setting it correctly, after setting the timeZone, I did a GetTimeZOneInformation to see if the timezone what I set earlier is matching and it does. So, I dont know how this setting is getting messed up internally.

I don't find any documentation about setting the Timezone or adjusting the Local Times/System times from an application on windows mobile 6.1

Will I have to muck around registry settings to get this working?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research on the internet, I found a blog which posted the similar issue.
And the issue seems to be in the OpenNetCF. When they are populating the TZData structure for each TimeZone, they ignored the StandardDate(when the daylight ended) and DayLightDate(when the daylight started). Since, these were missing in each TimeZoneInformation object, the standard timezones were getting defaulted to.

Here is the [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/WindowsCE-Embedded/30177413/set-timezone.aspx) that I found for this issue.

Thanks,

A